# How can I configure Git or Gitlab so that only a branch's owner is allowed to push into it?

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab, push

**Definitions:**

Who is the **owner** of a branch? The owner of a branch is the user who has **created** that branch.

**Situation:**

User **A** has created a branch from master called **A-branch**. Therefore, user **A** is the owner of **A-branch**.

User **B**, who is the colleague of user A, has created another branch from master called **B-branch**. Therefore, user **B** is the owner of **B-branch**.

**Desired restriction:**

User **A** must be the **only** user, who can **push**  changes into **A-branch**. (Because he is the owner of this branch)

User **B** must be the **only** user, who can **push**  changes into **B-branch**. (Because she is the owner of this branch)

**Questions:**

- Can user **A** push to **B-branch**? No
- Can user **A** pull 
  **B-branch**? Yes
- Can user **A** merge **B-branch** into his own branch? yes
- Can user **A** and **B** merge their branches into **master** ? Yes
- Should this recruction apply **automatically** on branch creation? Yes

How can I achieve such behavior described above in Gitlab?

Comment: Git itself does not record any kind of "ownership". GitLab's branch protection features (I assume it has some) are not part of Git, so GitLab will be using some outside-of-Git method to make such decisions in the first place; perhaps they record some sort of creation information outside of Git.

Answer (score 1):

As torek mentioned, Git doesn't record ownership of branches.  I'm not aware of any hosting platform for Git that allows branch restrictions on a per-user basis, especially automatically.

The typical assumption when one is sharing a repository with others is that those users are trusted to contribute to most branches in that repository, possibly with some particular restricted branches.

What you probably want to do in this case is allow the creation of forks for this repository and then have A and B push to their own forks.  They'll be able to fetch from each other's branches and open pull requests to merge their changes, but won't be able to push to each other's forks.

Comment: Dear @bk2204. Thank you for your answer. I am still searching for this functionality.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find it.  I suggest adopting a well-known alternative approach like using forks or simply clearly communicating standards and expectations to your team, if the latter is viable.